# Why this JavaScript Code isn't working as slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Is My Code.It has three parts.In the first script part i create image object and placed my Images.In the second script, i tried to loop the image using setTimeout function.But it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var image=new Array();
            image[0]=new Image();
            image[0].src='1.jpg';
            image[1]=new Image();
            image[1].src='2.jpg';



     function slideimage(){
     var slider=0;

       document.getElementById('slide').src=image[slider].src;

       if(slider<1){
       slider++
       }
       else{
       slider=0;
       }
      var t=setTimeout(function(){slideimage()},2000);
     }

     </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="slideimage()"> 
      <img src="1.jpg" id="slide" width="100" height="100"/> 
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Also, your `script` tags should be in either `head` or `body` of your `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to go about this would be to leverage `setInvterval`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var image = new Array();
 image[0] = new Image();
 image[0].src = '1.jpg';
 image[1] = new Image();
 image[1].src = '2.jpg';

 var slider = 0;
 function slideimage() {

  document.getElementById('slide').src = image[slider].src;

  if (slider < 1)       
    slider++;
  else
   slider = 0;    
 }
var x = window.setInterval(slideimage,2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `slider` variable will always be set back to `0` so you are setting the `image` source to `1.jpg` each time the `setTimout` will invoke `slideimage()`.

Just move the slider variable outside of the function body like so.

```
var slider = 0;
function slideimage() {
  document.getElementById('slide').src = image[slider].src;

  if (slider < 1) {
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you.Now it's working.But Why first  time it didn't work?is it the reason that when i have put the slider variable inside the slideimage() function it always got the 0 value instead of getting the other value like 1?Please give a answer.I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Yup, that is the case. The `slider` variable will always get set back to `0`.